# How to properly use linear layout in Android programming

Tags: android

I'm trying to create a layout that has a 4 categories on the page, and in each one 2 spinners with a title. However at the moment my layout is all over the place when i run an emulator. How can i fix this? i feel like i'm not understanding the concept of the layout properly since everything i add becomes rigid to the layout and i can't easily move things.

layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".Page1Fragment">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView0"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:background="#A0DD0A"
        android:text="TITLE" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayoutTop"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/LinearLayoutTopSub"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="134dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView1"
                android:layout_width="81dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:text="Weight" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="25dp" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/spinner"
                android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="25dp" />


        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/LinearLayoutTopSub2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="134dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView2"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:text="Computer" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="25dp" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/spinner2"
                android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="85dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp" />


        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="#FFFFFF">


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/LinearLayoutTopSub3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView4"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:text="Distance" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner4"
                android:layout_width="75dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="25dp" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner5"
                android:layout_width="75dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="0dp" />



        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/LinearLayoutTopSub4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView5"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:text="Other" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner6"
                android:layout_width="75dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="25dp" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner7"
                android:layout_width="75dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="0dp" />



        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Use RelativeLayout/ConstraintLayout  these are more flexible as compare to LinearLayout. 

Add UI what exactly you wanna do?

Comment: In your above code use  "android:weightSum" property to solve your problem.

Comment: what do i add that too?

Comment: My problem is the spinners are going ontop of each other

Comment: Post your UI so i can guide you how to do. I already told in previous comment use RelativeLayout/ConstraintLayout which provide you more flexibility.

If you face any-problem let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I have added new linear and removed weight. try this one.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".Page1Fragment">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView0"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:background="#A0DD0A"
    android:text="TITLE" />

<!-- adding new linear -->
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayoutTop"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/LinearLayoutTopSub"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="134dp"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/TextView1"
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:background="#FFFFFF"
                    android:text="Weight" />

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spinner"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/LinearLayoutTopSub3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="134dp"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/TextView3"
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:background="#FFFFFF"
                    android:text="Computer" />

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spinner3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spinner4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayoutBot"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/LinearLayoutBotSub"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="134dp"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/TextView4"
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:background="#FFFFFF"
                    android:text="Distance" />

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spinner9"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spinner7"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/LinearLayoutTopSub2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="134dp"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/TextView2"
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:background="#FFFFFF"
                    android:text="Others" />

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spinner2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spinner5"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```